# Was Caligula popular with the general Roman population?

Tags: roman-empire

Was Caligula, the Roman Emperor, popular with the general Roman population after his illness a few months into his reign?

Comment: What answer do you expect? There was no elections, and the results of opinion polls did not survive.

Comment: @Alex the idea that popular opinion could not be expressed or gauged outside polls is a modern Western fiction. In Caligula's case, at least before his illness, he was [extremely popular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caligula#Early_reign), as evidenced by public jubilation and the observations of contemporary historians.

Comment: @congusongus: Is Kim Il-sung popular in N Korea? Was Stalin popular in Soviet Union? Judging by "public jubilations" they are/were. Also according to some "contemporary historians".

Comment: @Alex yes, yes they were. In Kim Il-sung's case, extremely popular. Granted, the popularity was largely a product of coercion but that's a separate issue. Again, you seem to have conflated democracy with the concept of popularity. The definition of popularity is whether a lot of people like you, and people outside democracies can hold opinions too.

Answer (score 5):

When Caligula first became emperor, he was very popular with the people because he reduced taxes and instituted a few public reforms. After his illness, however, Caligula became increasingly paranoid and started to kill off those around him. He also began throwing lavish parties at his palace, and used up all the money in the Treasury in the process.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caligula#Early_reign

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that he was popular before his illness. Can you find any information about his actual popularity after his illness though? The actions that you have described may well have made people close to him (especially politically) dislike him but I do not know whether knowledge of these actions reached the general Roman population...

Comment: The only surviving contemporary sources are from Philo and Seneca, but they only briefly mention Caligula. But it was a pretty well-known fact that he liked to host lavish parties and waste money. Of course, like nearly all empires, the common people couldn't speak out against the emperor or they would get themselves killed.

Comment: There's no strong reason to doubt the general outline of Caligula's rise and fall, but it is *critical* to remember that all our surviving sources are from the Senatorial class (including their dependents). This was the aristocracy, and had a point of view that sometimes diverged greatly from that of the man-in-the-street. E.g., Caligula's killings were concentrated among the political types and the wealthy. This is *very* unpopular with them, but not necessarily so with the populace in general.